# How to do arithmetic operation in group values using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to do arithmetic operation in group values using javascript for example

```
var a = "5(8)+109/100";
```

I have used javascript eval() function to solve this,

Output :

```
var output = eval(a); //41.09
```

But eval() is not correct solution. Is there anything alternate solution to solve this task

[image: User can type in this textbox]

Comment: This example is strange. "5(8)" ?

Comment: A correct solution would likely involve creating abstract syntax trees.

Comment: Why is `eval` not the correct solution (assuming the about equivalent Function alternative has been considered) ? Some context is missing here, like for example how the formula to compute is produced. If what you want is a secure math formula parser, just use a lib.

Comment: I have tried fully with this eval() function only. But for security issue we wont use eval() function. I have searched in google about this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea
Can i have any lib for my references ?

Comment: @alistaircol can i have any example related to this task ?

Comment: Well you can parse it to make sure it is just numbers and arithmetic operators before you eval()

Comment: @epascarello I dont want to use eval() function.

Comment: Than you are going to have to build a parser. Have fun. You can use eval for it, just need to validate the data that it is valid before you run it.

Comment: yes bro i accept your answer, have to validate before eval. But this eval() has been remove due to security issue. so i can't use this eval function. so what asking is there any alternate solution to solve above task

Comment: What removed eval()? You can use `new Function()` but that is just like eval() or you can write a parser... AKA you write code that solves it just like you would if you did it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

`var a = "5(8)+109/100";
var res = ( new Function( 'return ' + a.split('(').join('*(') ) )(); 
console.log(res);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer this works for me, have to do some changes on my code.